# Does "perpendicular phase incoherence" satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: st.statistics, inequalities, euclidean-geometry, inner-product

I asked this question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4783968/222867, but even after a 200-point bounty, no solution was provided, only some thoughts regarding possible directions. So I'm now asking it here.

---

Let $S$ be the unit circle in the complex plane,
$$ S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}. $$

> For values $z_1^{(1)},z_1^{(2)},z_2^{(1)},z_2^{(2)},\ldots,z_k^{(1)},z_k^{(2)} \in S$, letting
> \begin{align*}
>  A &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(1)}z_j^{(2)}\right| \\
>  B_1 &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(1)}\right| \\
>  B_2 &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(2)}\right|,
>  \end{align*}
> do we necessarily have that
> $$ \sqrt{k^2 - A^2} \leq \sqrt{k^2 - B_1^2} \, + \sqrt{k^2 - B_2^2} \, ? $$

**Context:** For multivariate data where each coordinate is an angle, it is common to measure the *coherence* between two of the coordinates across the data set, by taking the magnitude of the mean of the complex exponential of the difference between the two coordinates. The question is whether the Pythagorean distance of this coherence from $1$ defines a pseudometric on the set of coordinates. (I know from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4770068/222867 that taking the "direct distance", namely one minus the coherence, fails; but the question that I am now asking is a "strictly weaker" question.) This is a highly relevant question for application of measures of phase-coherence of signals to ensembles of simultaneous time-series recordings, probably including phase-coherence of stationary stochastic processes as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing), but certainly at least including the various notions of time-localised deterministic phase-coherence described in Appendix B.1 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063520320300750.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice problem! I hope someone would come up with a nicer proof...

Yes, the inequality always holds. In what follows, I rename $z_j^{(1)}$ as $z_j$ and $z_j^{(2)}$ as $w_j$.

Multiplying all the $z_j$ by some $s_1\in S$ and all the $w_j$ by some $s_2\in  S$ we achieve
$\sum_j z_j, \sum_j w_j\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$; those multiplications make no effect to the inequality. Now let $z_j=\exp(i\alpha_j)$ and $w_j=\exp(i\beta_j)$. Then
$$
  B_1=\sum_j\cos\alpha_j, \quad
  B_2=\sum_j\cos\beta_j, \quad \text{and}\quad
  A\geq \left|\mathop{\mathrm{Re}}\sum_j z_iw_i\right|=\left|\sum_j\cos(\alpha_j+\beta_j)\right|.
$$
Therefore, it suffices to show that
$$
  f:=\sqrt{k^2-a^2}-\sqrt{k^2-b_1^2}-\sqrt{k^2-b_2^2}\leq 0,
$$
where
$$
  a=\sum_j\cos(\alpha_j+\beta_j), \quad
  b_1=\sum_j\cos \alpha_j, \quad
  b_2=\sum_j\cos \beta_j.
$$

The function $f$ (defined on $\mathbb R^{2k}$) attains its global maximum, as it is continuous and periodic (effective;y, it is a function on the compact $S^{2k}$). Take its point of maximum and assume, arguing indirectly, that the maximal value is positive, i.e., that $\sqrt{k^2-a^2}>\sqrt{k^2-b_1^2}+\sqrt{k^2-b_2^2}$ (as a consequence, $|a|<|b_1|,|b_2|$). This cannot hold if one of the square roots vanishes. So $f$ is differentiable at that point. Differentiation by $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$ gives
$$
  \frac{a}{\sqrt{k^2-a^2}}\sin(\alpha_j+\beta_j)=\frac{b_1}{\sqrt{k^2-b_1^2}}\sin\alpha_j=\frac{и_2}{\sqrt{k^2-b_2^2}}\sin\beta_j=:\mu_j.
  \qquad(*)
$$

Suppose that $\mu_j\neq 0$ for some $j$. Then
$$
  |\sin(\alpha_j+\beta_j)|=\pm|\sin\alpha_j||\cos\beta_j|\pm|\sin\beta_j||\cos\alpha_j|\leq |\sin\alpha_j|+|\sin\beta_j|,
$$
which, in view of $(*)$, after division by $|\mu_j|$ becomes
$$
  \frac{\sqrt{k^2-a^2}}{|a|}\leq\frac{\sqrt{k^2-b_1^2}}{|b_1|}+\frac{\sqrt{k^2-b_2^2}}{|b_2|}
  <\frac{\sqrt{k^2-b_1^2}}{|a|}+\frac{\sqrt{k^2-b_2^2}}{|a|};
$$
this contradicts our assumption.

It remains to check the case when all the $\mu_j$ are zero, If $b_1=0$ or $b_2=0$, then the desired inequality is trivial. Otherwise, all the sines involved should vanish, i.e., all angles are $0$ or $\pi$; this is already easy yet not very short.

If the $\delta_1$th fraction of the $\alpha_j$ and the $\delta_2$th fraction of the $\beta_j$ are $\pi$'s (we have $\delta_1,\delta_2\leq 1/2$), then the fraction of $-1$'s among the $\cos(\alpha_j+\beta_j)$ is at most $\delta_1+\delta_2$, so it suffices to check the inequality
$$
  \sqrt{1-(1-2\delta_1)^2}+\sqrt{1-(1-2\delta_2)^2}
  \geq\sqrt{1-\left(\max\{0,1-2\delta_1-2\delta_2\}\right)^2}.
$$
If $s:=\delta_1+\delta_2\leq 1/2$, the LHS is concave as a function in $\delta_1=s-\delta_2$, so it is at least
$$
  \sqrt{1-(1-0)^2}+\sqrt{1-(1-2s)^2}=\sqrt{1-(1-2\delta_1=2\delta_2)^2},
$$
as desired.

If $\delta_1+\delta_2\geq 1/2$ (but still $\delta_1,\delta_2\leq 1/2$), denote $1-2\delta_1=\sin\gamma\geq 1-\cos\gamma$ with $\gamma\in[0,\pi/2]$. Then $\sqrt{1-(1-2\delta_2)^2}\geq \sqrt{1-(2\delta_1)^2}\geq \sqrt{1-\cos^2\gamma}=\sin\gamma$. Therefore,
$$
  \sqrt{1-(1-2\delta_1)^2}+\sqrt{1-(1-2\delta_2)^2}
  \geq \cos\gamma+\sin\gamma\geq 1.
$$
as desired.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I'm afraid, it will probably be a day or two before I get the time to read through this carefully.

Comment: Sorry, there was a silly mistake in differentiation. Now it is corrected (and hopefully the argument is also correct;) ).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing why $\delta_1,\delta_2 \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That's because we made both $\sum_j z_j$ and $\sum_j w_j$ nonnegative.

Comment: But that was only to reduce the problem to showing the inequality $f \leq 0$; after that, in order to prove this inequality, you took a maximiser of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$ - is it obvious that such a maximiser exists with $b_1,b_2 \geq 0$?

Comment: I guess you can take a maximiser of $f$ over the compact subset $\{b_1,b_2 \geq 0\}$ of $S^{2k}$, but to then do the calculus that you did, you would need that this set includes at least a half-ray extending in every unsigned direction from every point - which is probably true, but not immediately obvious.

Comment: Okay, I've seen a possible way to resolve the issue: Take a maximiser of $f$ over the compact set $\{b_1,b_2 \geq 0\}$, and then when you suppose for a contradiction that $f$ is positive at this maximiser, you can conclude that both $b_1$ and $b_2$ are non-zero (just like you already did later on in the proof), and hence (by continuity of the functions $b_1,b_2$) the maximiser is in the interior of $\{b_1,b_2 \geq 0\}$ relative to $S^{2k}$, and so you can do the calculus as well as the rest of the argument.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. But in the remaining case you can simultaneously  switch the signs of all $z_i$ harmlessly.

Comment: Ah, I see: negating all the $z_i$ will negate $b_1$ and negate $a$, and hence preserve the values of $b_1^2$ and $a^2$; and analogously for the $w_i$. So it is always possible to force $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ both to be at most $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

This follows from

**Lemma.** For complex numbers $x,y$ in the unit disk we have $$\sqrt{1-\Re xy}\leqslant \sqrt{1-\Re x}+\sqrt{1-\Re y}.\tag{1}$$

**Proof.** Put $x=u+iv$,$y=p+iq$. Then, with fixed $p,u$ and the restrictions $|u+iv|\leqslant 1, |p+iq|\leqslant 1$ the maximal value of $1-\Re xy=1-pu+vq$ is clearly attained when both $v=\sqrt{1-u^2}$, $q=\sqrt{1-p^2}$, that is, $x$ and $y$ lie on the unit circle. But in this case $\sqrt{2(1-\Re x)}=|1-x|$; $\sqrt{2(1-\Re y)}=|1-y|=|x-xy|$; $\sqrt{2(1-\Re xy)}=|1-xy|$, and (1) follows from the triangle inequality for the complex numbers $1, x,xy$.

Denoting  $z_j^{(1)}\bar{z}_s^{(1)}=a_{j,s}$, $z_j^{(2)}\bar{z}_s^{(2)}=b_{j,s}$ for $(j,s)\in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}^2$, we read your inequality as $$\sqrt{\sum_{j,s}\left(1-\Re a_{j,s}b_{j,s}\right)}\leqslant 
\sqrt{\sum_{j,s}\left(1-\Re a_{j,s}\right)}+\sqrt{\sum_{j,s}\left(1-\Re b_{j,s}\right)}.\tag{2}$$
Thus, denoting $c_{j,s}^2=1-\Re a_{j,s}$, $d_{j,s}^2=1-\Re b_{j,s}$, by Lemma we have $1-\Re a_{j,s} b_{j,s}\leqslant (c_{j,s}+d_{j,s})^2,$ and (2) follows from the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$.

Comment: Sorry for being so slow to acknowledge - I've just read through this, and it's wonderful. I guess we only need (1) on the unit circle, not throughout the closed unit disk.